# Modelling underlying process of data from multiple subjects

Tags: regression, mixed-model

Suppose I have hormone levels from multiple subjects over a 24 hour period. I know that the underlying hormone level is periodic - eg the hormone is gradually released every 60 minutes, leading to a peak and then a trough. And this pattern should be pretty much the same for each subject. However, the magnitude of the peaks and troughs could be different. For example, subject 1 might have an average hormone level of 12$\mu$g/L and subject 2 might have an average hormone level of 20$\mu$g/L.

I want to model the underlying process so I have a baseline to compare to when a drug is administered.

1. Do I normalize each curve such they fall on the same range and then fit a model to this?
2. Or can I normalize and then fit a model to each individual and then get an average?
3. Would a generalized mixed effects model be useful here, since there are random effects between subjects (not necessarily normally distributed)?

Comment: To provide a useful answer it would be useful to provide a quick look at the data and tell us specifically what is your aim. In principle, these data are what mixed models are designed for.